# Expected number of non-empty boxes

Tags: expectation, means

Suppose 20 balls are thrown independently into 20 boxes (the probability that each ball lands into a particular box is 1/20). Find the expected number of non-empty boxes.

Comment: What did you try ? What are your thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.  Let $X_i$ be the random variable which is $1$ if, at end, the $i$-th box is non-empty and $0$ otherwise.

What is $P(\{X_i=1\})$?  What is $E(X_i)$?

Notice that you are looking for $E(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{20}E(X_i)$.

P.S. We have that $E(X_i)=P(\{X_i=1\})=(1-(19/20)^{20})$ for $i=1,\dots,20$.

Therefore the expected number of non-empty boxes is
$$20\cdot (1-(19/20)^{20})\approx 12.83028.$$

Comment: Furthermore, since all $X_i$ should be the same, the sum is just $20\mathbf{E}[X_i]$.

Comment: My answer is 12.83028. Is it correct?

Comment: @Mary Yes that's right. See my edited answer for the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Comment: @Mary You are welcome! Have a nice day.

Comment: How can we use the fact that there is only one favourable way that this can happen. I.e. all boxes have 1 ball each. So the probability of this happening is $1/(20^{20})$

Comment: @Upstart Yes, the probability that there are 20 non-empty boxes is $p_{20}=1/(20^{20})$, but here we are evaluating  the expected number of non-empty boxes, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{20}kp_k$